# How to create component with scss files in library angular

Tags: angular, sass, shared-libraries

I created a scss app and associated a library.
I want to create components with .scss files inside this library. But when I create a component inside the library, angular assigns it a css file automatically.

I created the application (named vega-libraries) with the scss option but not the library (polaris-common)

Here is a screenshot of the project with the tree view,I tried to change the css file of `totoComponent` in `toto.scss` as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

But when I do that, it generates an error of this type:

> Error: The loader "C:/Users/........toto/toto.component.css" didn't
> return a string.

How can I create components in my library with .scss files that work ?

Thank you for your help

EDIT :

```
 "polaris-common": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/polaris-common",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/polaris-common/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/polaris-common/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/polaris-common/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/polaris-common/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/polaris-common/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/polaris-common/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/polaris-common/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "vega-libraries"
}
```

Comment: what does the snippet of code in your angular.json look like for the lib?

Comment: Thanks for your nswer, I've edited my post with the snippet of angulr.json

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is for Angular 12. In prior versions it might be different. To set up `scss` as the default style format when doing `ng create component`, in `angular.json` under your project, add `schematics`:

```
"projectType": "library",
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "style": "scss"
    },
```

In an existing component, change `styleUrls` to reflect the path to your renamed `scss` file instead of `css`

```
// toto.component.ts

@Component({
  styleUrls: ['./toto.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: can confirm, still works in angular 15 (feb 2023)

Answer (score 5):

```
ng g c "filename" --style=scss
```

This is the best way I found actually.